# Two separate outputs appearing when using console.log once

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp, console.log

When I'm using `console.log` to display that my app has initialized I'm getting two outputs with the same value but one is from `VM66 main.js:34` and the other is from just `main.js:34`. This really wouldn't be an issue, however, when I'm using `console.log` to output another value such as the length of an array the values are completely different. `VM66` is saying that my array is empty and my main file says that it has a length of one; which is true, my array has a length of one.

I'm using webpack-stream with gulp and the htmlWebpackPlugin. Below is my `webpack.config.js` file

```
module.exports = 
{
entry: "./src/editor/js/main.js",
    output: {
      path: __dirname + "./devBuild/editor/js",
      filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      }
      ]
    },
      mode: "development",
      plugins: [
          new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
              title: "Developer version" ,
              template: __dirname + "/src/editor/index.html",
              filename: __dirname + './devBuild/editor/index.html'
          })
     ]
  }
```

If you require anymore information please let me know, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I had included `<script src="./js/bundle.js"></script>` already in my template html file. So when the htmlWebpackPlugin compiled my code it inserted another `<script src="./js/bundle.js"></script>` resulting in my code running twice.